# Ros unmet dependencies instal issue on Ubuntu 13.1

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I was trying to install ROS Indigo on ubuntu 13.1 but I keep getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226943/ros-unmet-dependencies-instal-issue-on-ubuntu-13.1/) by [meep](https://answers.ros.org/users/25977/meep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-17**:
Ubuntu 13.10 is no longer supported by Ubuntu, and because of that, ROS has stopped supporting it. Can you upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04, which is the long-term supported version?

**Comment by [meep](https://answers.ros.org/users/25977/meep/) on 2016-02-18**:
I can upgrade but there is no other way to install ROS on 13.1 correct?

**Comment by [meep](https://answers.ros.org/users/25977/meep/) on 2016-02-18**:
Would installing it from source be any different?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-18**:
You can try installing from source or you can try to resolve the dependency issues yourself. Unfortunately, there isn't enough information in the error messages from apt to help you resolve issues here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you really want to dig into it, you can start with one of the packages that is blocking desktop-full, try to install that package, and follow the broken dependencies down the chain until you figure out what is wrong.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0